# Postgres search query contains stopwords

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I'm trying to debug a search query that contains a stopword, which is also a lexeme in the document text.

The query is 'up' and the document is 'UPS Store'. I would like to be able to show the user the document, when the user enters 'up', but instead I get this message:

```
NOTICE:  text-search query contains only stop words or doesn't contain lexemes, ignored
```

How can I fix this issue?